# Decoding or Escaping HEX code numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, string, hex, ascii, decode

I need your help.

How do you decode or escape HEX code numbers in a string?

```
var str = "Pneus de contrefa\00E7on. Prot\00E9gez-Vous"
```

I should mention that the string above is generated above is from a Database query.

The converted string should read as follows:

```
var str = "Pneus de contrefaçon. Protégez-Vous"
```

Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You need a \u instead of just \ before the four hex characters of unicode.